# Pass windows environment variable as docker environment variable

Tags: windows, docker, environment-variables, spring-batch, docker-for-windows

we are trying to pass windows environment variables as docker environment variable, does anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

This can be achieved easily on linx with below command

```
docker run -it  --env-file <$(env | grep abc) ubuntu
```

But similar command on windows does not work

```
docker run -it  --env-file=&set user ubuntu
docker run -it  --env-file < $(&set user) ubuntu
```

Tried to achieve through batch command,

```
for /f usebackq %F in (`set user`) do docker run -it --rm -e %F ubuntu
```

But this iterates the env variables and pass only one env per run

Any help will be highly appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the docker run command with environment names only, without the values and docker will pick the values set in the Windows environment variables when set/ available.

Example
Instead of running `docker run -p 8080:8080 -e FIRST_NAME='John' -e LAST_NAME='DOE'`, you first make sure those environment variables are set in your user/ system and run the same command in the format `docker run -p 8080:8080 -e FIRST_NAME -e LAST_NAME`.